# Load information from text field to table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

Hi I am trying to make an app that has a text field, tableview and a button.
When you press the button it adds the information from the text field to de tableview.
Do any one know when I can find a tutorial for this? I had one on a book but I cant find it.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code so far:

code of .h

```
@interface BlockNotasViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
IBOutlet UITableView *tableNota;}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textonota;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableNota;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * arrayNota;
- (IBAction)AddNota:(id)sender;
@end
```

code of .m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textonota.delegate = self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
 }
 - (IBAction)AddNota:(id)sender {
[arrayNota addObject: textonota.text];
[tableNota reloadData];
```

}

```
//TableView------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [arrayNota count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}
 - (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
 {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] init];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [arrayNota objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
//----------------------------------------------

@end
```

No more errors but the button doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a NSMutableArray property that contains all the cells you want to add to the tableView.

When that button is pressed, you create a cell with a tag, and set text of that cell to the text of your UITextField:

```
 cell.textLabel.text = aUITextField.text;
```

then add the cell into that NSMutableArray, and call [tableView reloadData] to refresh the table view.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath delegate, you can use that tag to determine which cell in NSMutableArray to return, for example:

```
[return [self.cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: yes, I gives my an idea of how to do it but do you know a guide I could follow?

Comment: the things I am having trouble are the array with the cells and what to put on the button

Comment: for the error, do you sure the current class is subclass of UITableView? It seems like UIView receive UITableView's delegate method. here is a tutorial of UITableView:http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/

Comment: yes the UIView recieves the delegate method from the UITableView, I will remove that and see what happens next

Comment: the table is working now I didn't set the methods properly, now the button is giving error

Comment: yes it was a typo, I correct it but now the button do nothing

Comment: 1. make sure the button is wired up corrently by adding a "NSLog(@"button pressed")" 2.add something like for(NSArray *subArray in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"Array in myArray: %@",subArray);
}to see the content in your array

Comment: the button works but the array when I press it get's null doesn't add the textfield.text

Comment: where do you create arrayNota? in viewDidLoad? is it a property or instance variable?

Comment: the array is created in viewDidLoad, is a property variable

Comment: According to your code: NSMutableArray *arrayNota; your array is not a property, you should use property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayNota; in .h file to make it a property and synthesize it in .m file

Comment: could you post entire code both .h and .m file? so I can have a overall seeing of where is wrong

Comment: I think you forgot to initial NSMuableArray, you can put it in ViewDidLoad, arrayNota = [[NSMuableArray alloc] init];

Comment: sorry I couldn't try it earlier but it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should keep mutable array with strings. And use this array for fill content of tableview as data source. In delegate method - (UITableViewCell*) tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you  will create UITableViewCell if needed like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"identifier"]; 
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier: @"identifier"] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; 
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myMutableArray count]; 
}

- (IBAction) pressButton: (id) sender
{
    [myMutableArray addObject: textField.text];
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Every book for iOS developers contains information about UITableView. 
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming

Comment: Hi I used your code but got an error I put it on the original post